# Multiplicar números dentro de un arreglo

Tags: c#, array, recursión

Tengo un arreglo de n números generados aleatoriamente y quiero multiplicar los números que se generen entre si usando recursión. Por ejemplo, si al hacer el vector este fuera {2, 5, 6} que me de como resultado 2 x 5 x 6 = 60.

Tengo este método pero no retorna el valor correcto:

```
public int Multiplicacion(int n)
{                
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return vector[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return vector[n - 1] * Multiplicacion(n - 1);                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor explicar mas su problema. Usando el arreglo {2,5,6}, cual numero es el input `n`? y que es el output con su codigo ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Una **función recursiva** tiene dos casos principales, el **caso base** que es la condición que al cumplirse hace que la función deje de llamarse a si misma y devuelva un resultado, en este ejemplo sería cuando la **variable n** sea igual a la longitud del arreglo y el **caso recursivo**, en el cual se vuelve a llamar a la función. Hasta tanto no se cumpla el **caso base** la función continuará invocándose recursivamente. Te propongo dos formas de resolver tu problema usando recursividad.

**Recursividad clásica**:

```
int[] numeros = {2, 5, 6};

public int Multiplicacion(int[] vector, int n)
{           
    if (n == vector.Length)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return vector[n] * Multiplicacion(vector, n + 1);     
}
```

La usarías de esta forma:

```
int multiplicatoria = Multiplicacion(numeros, 0);
```

Aquí se pasa como parámetro el arreglo y el índice **0** y se retorna la multiplicación de todos los elementos del arreglo.

**Recursividad de cola**:

```
int[] numeros = {2, 5, 6};

public int Multiplicacion(int[] vector, int total, int n)
{           
    if (n == vector.Length)
    {
        return total;
    }

    return  Multiplicacion(vector, total * vector[n], n + 1); 
}
```

La usarías de esta forma:

```
int multiplicatoria = Multiplicacion(numeros, 1, 0);
```

Se pasa como parámetro el arreglo, el total actual que en este caso es **1**, ya que aún no se ha hecho ninguna multiplicación y el índice inicial del arreglo.

Como comentario final te digo que a diferencia de la recursión estándar, la **recursividad de cola** permite que el lenguaje de programación subyacente optimice el manejo de la llamada recursiva, reduciendo así la sobrecarga de recursos y aumentando la escalabilidad general y el rendimiento de la función. Este es un tema un poco más avanzado y muy interesante, si deseas abundar más en este tema te recomiendo investigues en Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Primero una aclaración: En `C++` un vector es sinónimo de `array` unidimensional, en `JAVA` es una estructura de datos, pero en `C#` los vectores son una clase que representa la noción matemática de vectores, los puedes sumar, multiplicar, realizar el producto cruz, etc. Lo que tu tienes es una estructura de datos con índice, como lo puede ser un `array` o un `IList`, no es un `vector`

Tu estas realizando la recursión a través del índice, y me parece que estas ingresando como argumento el largo del `array`, razón por la que haces `n-1`, es decir vas recorriendo el array desde el final al principio con un índice que está desplazado en `-1`, entonces tu problema radica que la comprobación de parada de la recursividad no estas considerando dicho desplazamiento, es decir tu código debería ser:

```
public int Multiplicacion(int n)
{  
    //if (n == 0)              
    if (n - 1 == 0) //agregar el desplazamiento
    {
        return vector[0];
    }
    else //este else sobra, deberías colocar directamente el return
    {
        return vector[n - 1] * Multiplicacion(n - 1);                   
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, existe otra forma de recorrer un `array` mediante recursión, que es ir pasando un array más corto (un subarray) en lugar del índice. Por ejemplo partimos con el array `[2,5,6]`, luego pasamos `[5,6]` y finalmente `[6]`. Esto se puede realizar fácilmente usando [Rangos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)

Ejemplo

```
 public static int Multiplicacion(int[] array) => array.Length switch
 {
     0 => 0, //si el array es vacio retornamos cero
     1 => array[0],
     _ => array[0] * Multiplicacion(array[1..])
 };
```

```
Console.WriteLine( Multiplicacion([2,5,6]) ); //60
```